# link between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I have two tables:

`TableA` which contains description of all products :

```
codeProduct   description

    1              ok
    2              yes
```

`TableB` contains hierarchy between products only with codes :

```
level_1 level_2 level_3 level_4
1       2       23      75
1       2       53      85
```

How could I get a final table that contains for each level the description

```
level_1 description_1 level_2 description_2 level_3 description_3 level_4 description_4
```

Comment: What is your expected result here exactly? You seem to have told us what columns you want, but not what is contained in said columns. What have you tried so far to achieve what you're after, and why didn't it work? Did you get a error, unexpected results, something *else*?

Comment: hint: `INNER JOIN`

Comment: Are you just looking for a `CROSS JOIN`? Please share the desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need  use  of tableA several time each time you need a value for a column in tableB

```
select b.level_1
    , a1.description description_1
    , b.level_2
    , a2.description description_2
    , b.level_3
    , a3.description description_3
    , b.level_4 
    , a4.description description_4 
from  TableB b 
left join  TableA a1 on a1.codeProduct = b.level_1 
left join  TableA a2 on a2.codeProduct = b.level_2 
left join  TableA a3 on a3.codeProduct = b.level_3 
left join  TableA a4 on a4.codeProduct = b.level_4
```

use left join if you not all matching value between the two tables  or INNER JOIN if you have all the macthing values

```
select b.level_1
    , a1.description description_1
    , b.level_2
    , a2.description description_2
    , b.level_3
    , a3.description description_3
    , b.level_4 
    , a4.description description_4 
from  TableB b 
INNER join  TableA a1 on a1.codeProduct = b.level_1 
INNER join  TableA a2 on a2.codeProduct = b.level_2 
INNER join  TableA a3 on a3.codeProduct = b.level_3 
INNER join  TableA a4 on a4.codeProduct = b.level_4
```

Comment: I have a problem with duplicated rows when I use inner join. This is exactly my problem

Comment: if you have really duplicated  rows  .. then you can add  DISTINCT  ..  anyway check if you have properly joined  the tables  ..

Comment: @csharp, check the data integrity on your `TableA`. Start with something like `select codeProduct, count(*) as cnt from TableA group by codeProduct order by cnt desc` to see if that table is where your duplicate values are coming from.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
CREATE TABLE #TABLEA
(
  CODEPRODUCT INT NOT NULL
, DESCRIPTION VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #TABLEA VALUES (1, 'ok') ;
INSERT INTO #TABLEA VALUES (2, 'yes');

CREATE TABLE #TABLEB
(
  LEVEL_1 INT NOT NULL
, LEVEL_2 INT NOT NULL
, LEVEL_3 INT NOT NULL
, LEVEL_4 INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO #TABLEB VALUES(1, 2, 23, 75) , (1, 2, 53, 85);

SELECT #TABLEB.LEVEL_1
     , TA_L1.DESCRIPTION AS DESCRIPTION1
     , #TABLEB.LEVEL_2
     , TA_L2.DESCRIPTION AS DESCRIPTION2
     , #TABLEB.LEVEL_3
     , TA_L3.DESCRIPTION AS DESCRIPTION3
     , #TABLEB.LEVEL_4
     , TA_L4.DESCRIPTION AS DESCRIPTION4
FROM #TABLEB
LEFT JOIN #TABLEA TA_L1
ON #TABLEB.LEVEL_1 = TA_L1.CODEPRODUCT
LEFT JOIN #TABLEA TA_L2
ON #TABLEB.LEVEL_2 = TA_L2.CODEPRODUCT
LEFT JOIN #TABLEA TA_L3
ON #TABLEB.LEVEL_3 = TA_L3.CODEPRODUCT
LEFT JOIN #TABLEA TA_L4
ON #TABLEB.LEVEL_4 = TA_L4.CODEPRODUCT;
```

Result:

```
LEVEL_1, DESCRIPTION1, LEVEL_2, DESCRIPTION2, LEVEL_3, DESCRIPTION3, LEVEL_4, DESCRIPTION4
    1   ok  2   yes 23  NULL    75  NULL
    1   ok  2   yes 53  NULL    85  NULL
```

Comment: Your answer has the correct code, but will be more useful to the OP and to anyone who might come across this question in the future if you include an explanation of _why_ the code is correct. See scaisEdge's answer, which has largely the same code that you do, to see what I mean.